# How to install YAML 1.1.1 into php

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0, yaml

I want to use yaml_parse_file() function in cakephp2 but I have the error

"Fatal error: Call to undefined function yaml_parse_file() in D:\Downloads\xampp\htdocs\carebody-2012-\app\Lib\RoadYaml.php on line 7".

I think that I'm having this error because I dont have yaml in my php.
The problem is I dont know how to install the yaml file that I downloaded ?

Comment: After installation dont forget to write `extension=yaml.so` without any quotes in `php.ini` file. Also check this page: http://hu1.php.net/yaml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using apache2, edit file `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`.

Add `extension=yaml.so` in the dynamic extensions section.

For the full exemple :

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Dynamic Extensions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; If you wish to have an extension loaded automatically, use the following
; syntax:
;
;   extension=modulename.extension
;
; For example, on Windows:
;
;   extension=msql.dll
;
; ... or under UNIX:
;
;   extension=msql.so
;
; ... or with a path:
;
;   extension=/path/to/extension/msql.so
;
; If you only provide the name of the extension, PHP will look for it in its
; default extension directory.
;
extension=yaml.so
```